# How do I climb Bell Tower #9?

Tags: far-cry-4

Any one have any solution to climb this tower? I've only managed the first ladder, but I can't jump the gap (if that's what I'm supposed to do).

[image: Map screenshot of Bell Tower in question]

Comment: You can also reach most of the tower tops with a buzzer. That's how I did most of them.

Comment: This one seems to be to high up in the mountains, the buzzer wont go there

Comment: there is a buzzer in the airport near by which i was able to use to get to the top

Answer (score 5):

I figured it out, You need to "look up" more when you jump, then it's easier.

Answer (score 1):

Even on PC with the XBox controller, I couldn't hang the corner and hit jump at the same time.
Smash the railing down so you can get more of a run and jump the gap at something of an angle.

If you picture the opening with the railing there, knock all of the railing down. Now, take 2-3 steps left (back towards the ladder), turn and face the platform you're trying to get to. Now it should be a standard running jump to get there. So, I'm not going all the way back to the ladder, maybe 1/2 way.

I succeeded the first time after doing that. Not sure if it's just easy without the railing or I got lucky.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and I found the solution. 
you have first to click on w button then the sprint button (shift) then space to jump. 
in this order you will be abmle to made a big jump. Befor this solution i was using shift then w button then space but it don't work in this order.

Answer (score 1):

1: You can reach the lowest roof of this tower with a buzzer, that will get you past the longest jump.

2: If you have a Logitech keyboard or other KB that won't support three presses, you can make the jump by temporarily remapping sprint (shift) to middle mouse... works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Once you climb the ladder. Start sprinting from right there. Continue sprinting while you turn left and then take a jump. You will cross the gap easily.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with the PC is that unless you have the correct keyboard, you cannot use three keys (shift - W - Spacebar) at the same time. This prevents you from jumping the gap. I cannot do it with my Loagitec, but can with my gaming keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the lip of the jumping off point, there's a plank of wood just jutting out. Centre that on your reticle, then back off, facing the landing platform, look up to the beam opposite and use the plank as the jumping off point. It's a very precise jump/timing thing but it can be done (after a few tries).

Answer (score -1):

I was stuck for ages! Hold the left analogue stick and jump forward at the same time... Then you can reach.

Comment: Running on a PC, I've tried jumping, but it seems not to work.

Answer (score -1):

After knocking down the railing and running at wall and jumping to left did it, but now stuck at forth climb. Trying to get across beam and up, keep falling to ground. We need a grapple gun, haha